# Show posts of created Category in Custom post types

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, web

1. I've created a custom post type in function.php.
2. I have added category function for the custom post type.
3. I've created for ex. Post 1 and Post 2.
4. Than I've created 2 categories Category 1, Category 2.

and set in wp panel that post 1 has category 1, and post 2 has category 2,
but posts don't show on the category page, i'have tried to edit category.php but nothing happens.

do You have any ideas on how to solve this?
Which function I should add to category.php?

functions.php

```
/* Custom Post Type Start */

function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'news',
    // CPT Options
    array(
      'labels' => array(
       'name' => __( 'news' ),
       'singular_name' => __( 'News' )
      ),
      'taxonomies' => array('category'),  //add this....
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => false,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news'),
     )
    );
    }
    // Hooking up our function to theme setup
    add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );


/* Edit custom post type */

    function cw_post_type_news() {
        $supports = array(
      
        'title', // post title
        'editor', // post content
        'thumbnail', // featured images
        'excerpt', // post excerpt
        'custom-fields', // custom fields
        'revisions', // post revisions
        'post-formats', // post formats
        );
        $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Produkty', 'plural'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Produkt', 'singular'),
        'menu_name' => _x('Produkty', 'admin menu'),
        'name_admin_bar' => _x('produkty', 'admin bar'),
        'add_new' => _x('Dodaj', 'add new'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Dodaj produkt'),
        'new_item' => __('Nowy '),
        'edit_item' => __('Edytuj '),
        'view_item' => __('Zobacz'),
        'all_items' => __('Wszystkie produkty'),
        'search_items' => __('Wyszukaj'),
        'not_found' => __('Brak'),
        );
        $args = array(
        'supports' => $supports,
      
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news'),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        );
        register_post_type('news', $args);
        }
      
        add_action('init', 'cw_post_type_news');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom taxonomy for your custom post type, because If category.php calls for post type = post, then your post type dosen't get into query.

Example for custom taxonomy:

```
function taxonomies_examle() {
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Example', 'Example' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Example', 'Example' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Example' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Example' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Example' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Example:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Example' ), 
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Example' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Example' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Example' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Example' ),
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public' => true,  // it's not public, it shouldn't have it's own permalink, and so on
    'publicly_queriable' => true,  // you should be able to query it
    'show_ui' => true,  // you should be able to edit it in wp-admin
    'exclude_from_search' => false,  // you should exclude it from search results
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,  // you shouldn't be able to add it to menus
    'has_archive' => true,  // it shouldn't have archive page
    'rewrite' => true,  // it shouldn't have rewrite rules
    'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
);

register_taxonomy( 'examle', 'your-custom-post-type', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'taxonomies_examle', 0);
```

Then you can create taxonomy-example.php and you can there query your post from categories.

Answer (score 0):

The good way to show post from custom post type, you need to use the template file taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php, or taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php.

But really, using category.php or taxonomy.php really may not be what you want to do. Have you tried using archive-{post-type}.php, for displaying the archive index list of posts from your Custom Post Type?

If you are using SEO friendly permalinks then your CPT’s URL will most likely be something like this:

http://example.com/movies

If you are not using SEO friendly permalinks, then your custom post type URL will be something like this:

http://example.com/?post_type=movies

Don’t forget to replace example.com with your own domain name and movies with your custom post type name.

But if you need to show post in default category page, you need to do this :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_custom_post_type' );
function add_my_custom_post_type( $query ) {
    if ($query->is_main_query()) 
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'news' ) );
    return $query;
}
```